# Controller functionality - if user is not logged in send them to specific page (not wp_login)

Tags: wp-redirect

This sounds dead bang simple, but I just can't figure it out.

I want the following functionality:

*If user is not logged in and they try to access anywhere on the site (including the homepage) - send them to a specific page.*

I tried, adding the following but received a "not redirecting properly" message:

```
if (!is_user_logged_in() ) {
 wp_redirect ('/public' );
 exit;
 }
```

I guess if I can add a clause to the if statement saying and the page I am accessing is not the public page, but I'm not quite sure how to that properly.

Any plugins that I see out there redirect to the wordpress login screen.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

MG

Comment: try the absolute url: `bloginfo('wpurl').'/public';`

Comment: or `home_url('/public')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you are getting a `not redirecting properly` message is because you are creating an endless loop of redirects. They get redirected to `/public` but because they are not logged in they get redirected again and again and again...

Try this code instead:

```
if( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page("public") )
{
    wp_redirect( site_url("/public") );
    exit;
}
```

I'm assuming that `/public` is a page you have setup.

Comment: If this answer answers your question, you should **accept it**, by clicking the **checkmark** beneath the answer up/down vote arrows.